# What screwdriver do I need to remove the fans inside an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-42-R5ED laptop?

Tags: laptop, fan, screws

I’m not really tech savy, but I need a screwdriver to unscrew my fans and hard drive and I am not too sure what screwdriver I need.

This is something I want to unscrew to re-apply the thermal flash and blah blah. This is prob a dumb question but I just need the screwdriver to unscrew it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those screws in the picture are Philips screws. They are either number 1 or number 0.

You can get good, high quality, Philips drivers at Home Depot, Lowes in the US, North America, or at a good hardware store where you live.

Buy top quality screwdrivers so as not to damage the screw head. This is easily done with a poor quality driver, or a driver that does not fit properly, so you will want to take care.

I have these tools and have removed / replaced screws like this.

Comment: So i Should get a Philip #0 head screwdriver?

Comment: Yes, for sure. That will do what you need. I have one here on my desk for modest tasks.

Comment: @Namzelor These types of screwdrivers usually come in sets. This [tool set is available at a Mac specific store](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/TOOLKIT14/), but for $12 (US) you can get the Phillips head screwdriver you need and more.